# Using BDD style of tests

Tags: c#, bdd

When using BDD for higher level of tests, then this language in tests - given,when,then seems easy to understand.I am using C#.So,what I do is name the class as "whenthishappens",setup is the "given",and then I have tests.But,how to use this style of BDD when writing tests for a class method.Or,should I have just tests named "shouldDoXXX".?

Comment: Have you considered any of the BDD frameworks available for .NET? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307895/what-is-the-most-mature-bdd-framework-for-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally name my tests `shouldDoXXXX` where the test name describes what it should do for all similar contexts. So I might say `shouldAddUpTwoNumbersCorrectly`. This is a bit different to the way a lot of BDDers do it - the Ruby crowd particularly seem to like `shouldAddTwoPlusTwoToMakeFour`, so repeating the particular example they use. Whichever works for you!

Inside the test, I often write comments as Given / When / Then:

```
public void ShouldAddUpTwoNumbersCorrectly() 
{
    // Given two numbers
    // When I give them to the summer
    // Then the result should be the sum of the two numbers
}
```

Then I fill in the code between the comments. If the test is very simple I may skip the comments.

I don't bother with English-readable frameworks for a class test, because the audience is technical and capable of reading code. The BDD frameworks which do Given / When / Then were created largely to help with conversations with non-technical stakeholders, and to encourage developers to use their language. I don't find them useful at a class level. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a blog I wrote about BDD style tests for MSTest based code:

[http://mrclyfar.blogspot.com/2010/02/amazing-mapping-demo-at-ted-2010.html](https://mrclyfar.blogspot.com/2010/02/amazing-mapping-demo-at-ted-2010.html). I used ideas from this [blog](https://saintgimp.org/2009/01/20/bdd-with-mstest/) post.

Personally I use [StoryQ](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=storyq) for my tests. StoryQ is a testing framework similar to MSpec and SpecFlow, in that you can write your tests out in a more descriptive manner. In the beginning, I did try using BDD naming for MSTest style code, but I found it to be less flexible then I wanted. I then experimented with MSpec, which is awesome.

In the end I chose StoryQ since it had that little bit more verbosity about it which I like. Makes it easier for me to write descriptive tests without having to use context inheritance.

Comment: So,when you are writing unit test for a class,you use given\when\then format? So,you will have multiple classes for testing a class,since when represents a scenario

Comment: Yeah, you would have multiple classes for the `when` scenarios. That is the suggested practise described in the Eric Lee blog post I gave.

Comment: I just dived into StoryQ.And,was able to write test.I am using MBUnit Gallio to run tests.But,I don't see the descriptive output anywhere in the story format

Comment: I don't think the output for StoryQ will work with Gallio. I can only see the descriptive text in my MSTest output window, or Resharper test runner. I don't Gallio supports StoryQ.

Comment: Just use "ExecuteWithReport", and have a look at the generated report file :)

Answer (score 1):

This C# framework does exactly what you require, and allows you to start your test method names with IWantTo

```
public void IWantTo...()
```

It is open source and found at

- http://kernowcode.github.io/UBADDAS/

Converts this ...

```
[Test]
public void IWantToRegisterANewUser()
{
  ICustomer customer = new Customer();

  SoThat(MyBusinessValue.IncreaseCustomerBase)
    .As(new User())
    .Given(customer.Register)
    .When(customer.Confirm_Registration)
    .Then(customer.Login);
}
```

to this ...

```
I want to register a new user
  So that Increase customer base
       As user
    Given Register customer
     When Confirm customer registration
     Then Login customer
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at the [BDD for C# NUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706968/bdd-for-c-sharp-nunit/49096333#49096333). An alternative way might be to use some C# libraries, which help writing BDD-like unit tests with readable descriptions.